# Removing packages from a local, apt-mirror based repo

Tags: ubuntu, mirror, apt-mirror

I currently have local repo installed using `apt-mirror` as was described in [linuxtechi](https://www.linuxtechi.com/setup-local-apt-repository-server-ubuntu/) website. It has `deb-amd64` data of 2 versions of Ubuntu, namely, `20.04` and `22.04`. Now I would like to support only `22.04` and remove the `20.04` only data with minimal effort. Is there a smart way to do this? I do not mind downloading the entire data again, if necessary, but do not wish to do the set up again. And if it isn't possible, what is the best way to recreate the site as I find `apt-mirror` being a little difficult to maintain.

Thanks in advance for any feedback and help.